# Bootstrap 4.0 SASS variable reference

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I found a variable in the bootstrap 4.0 alpha _variable.scss file:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 544px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;
```

How do I reference this variable if I wanted to refernce something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: $grid-breakpoints(md) ){...}
```

This does not work...any advise?

Comment: Hi, my question is a little different, as I am trying to target one of the chain variables. The one you linked as duplicate is asking for chain variables with @each function which I am not after. I want to target just 1 variable from the chain access.

Comment: And what do you think the variables created in the loop contain?  The difference between a mapping of mappings and a mapping is that you call the function that selects the element from the mapping one less time.

Comment: The very first line of the highest voted answer of the question I marked this as a duplicate of has your answer.

Comment: @user1467439 you can just use `map-get` [like this](http://www.codeply.com/go/RlKqmar2VD)

Comment: Thanks @Skelly that was the correct way to go :)